# Panel problem (xfce) in Xubuntu 12

Tags: xfce-panel

I would like to delete the "Window Buttons" from the panel.. there is no option to do such thing. What can I do?

Here's what I've tried:
Panel -> Add New Items... -> Window Buttons (switch between open windows using buttons)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in **Settings** > **Panel**. Remove or Add objects in the "objects" tab.

Answer (score 0):

You have to right-click on the panel, then choose **Panel > Panel Preferences...**, then change to the **Items** tab, select the **Window Buttons** item and click the remove button:
[image: Imgur]

That should do it.